How can I write automated tests that work across multiple native Android applications?
I'm working on a project where I need to write automated tests for multiple Android applications using Appium. All of these applications are native Android apps, but they have different UI designs and functionalities. I plan on using Appium. How should I proceed? Any answers are appreciated.
I was thinking about using Page Object Model. I could store locators of each app in different files and then fetch those locators conditionally when performing the test. I'm not sure if this is how it should be done though.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
